# Using Mac Cocoa Controls with OpenFrameworks and GLUT

Tags: macos, cocoa, glut, openframeworks

I'm struggling figuring out how to get Mac Cocoa Controls working with OpenFrameworks.

What I'm looking for is a way to create cocoa controls and add them as subviews to the window that open frameworks uses. Because it's GLUT I can't figure out where to get a pointer that I can add subviews to.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not on Mac, I can't test it, but the most promising addon for openFrameworks is the one from memo [here](https://github.com/memo/msalibs/tree/master/ofxCocoa). It replaces the GLUT stuff with Cocoa but seems to be a bit outdated. I would recommend to have a look at the example code which comes with this addon to see if it fits your need and could be a start for adding cocoa controls "on top of it". If its not the right one, you can have a look at the official openFrameworks addons index [here](http://ofxaddons.com/), there are several other addons for cocoa, maybe they do the job also.

Comment: thanks for the response, bummer though I've tried all the addons and I can't get any of them working (add an NSButton to the window). If you had time to throw a sample together that'd be sweet.